# How to change decimal separator in ExecuteReader c#

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, executereader

How to change decimal separator in string, e.g. in mnoz_obj item the returned value is 24,000 and I need to have 24.000. The values are from database to JSON.
I tried ToString(new CultureInfo etc.) but this doesn't work. I expect that myString.Replace(",",".") is not correct way to do it.

```
public static string getDoklad()
        {
            var dbCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
            string[] fileArguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            List<ZebraPolozky> zebraPolozky = new List<ZebraPolozky>();
            using (var cn = new OdbcConnection(dbCon))
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cis06zebrap";
                cn.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ZebraPolozky zebraPolozka = new ZebraPolozky
                            {
                                doklad = reader["doklad"].ToString(),
                                sklad = reader["sklad"].ToString(),
                                reg = reader["reg"].ToString(),
                                mnoz_obj = reader["mnoz_obj"].ToString(),
                                mnoz_vyd = reader["mnoz_vyd"].ToString(),
                                kc_pce = reader["kc_pce"].ToString(),
                                sarze = reader["sarze"].ToString(),
                                datspo = reader["datspo"].ToString(),
                                veb = reader["veb"].ToString(),
                                poc2 = reader["poc2"].ToString(),
                                pvp06pk = reader["pvp06pk"].ToString(),
                                znacky = reader["znacky"].ToString(),
                                stav = reader["stav"].ToString(),
                                //prac = reader["prac"].ToString(),
                                //exp = reader["exp"].ToString()
                            };
                            zebraPolozky.Add(zebraPolozka);
                        }
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
            //var collw = new { polozky = zebraPolozky };
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zebraPolozky);
            return jsonString;
        }
```

```
{
    "doklad": "568375",
    "sklad": "901",
    "reg": "185121",
    "mnoz_obj": "24,000",
    "mnoz_vyd": "0,000",
    "kc_pce": "240,72",
    "sarze": "",
    "datspo": "",
    "veb": "24,00",
    "poc2": "1",
    "pvp06pk": "116783437",
    "znacky": "R1902",
    "stav": "0"
  }
```

Comment: `reader["mnoz_obj"]` returns an `object` but the reader should give its original type. If it's a `decimal`, just cast it and use the .ToString() overload you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OdbcDataReader` gives the value in its native format as stated in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_Odbc_OdbcDataReader_Item_System_String_).

You should then be able to cast it and use the overload of `.ToString()` you need.

Try something like:

```
((decimal)reader["mnoz_obj"]).ToString("N2")
```